# #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, join, union

Please help me out

```
SELECT mainmenu.mid FROM (
(
SELECT 
    content_info.ContentID, 
    content_info.Title,
    menu_list_article.MenuID as article_parent,
    subsubmenu.title as article_parent_title,
    submenu.sid,
    submenu.title as sid_title,
    mainmenu.mid,
    mainmenu.title as mid_title,
    mainmenu.module
FROM `content_info`
JOIN menu_list_article ON menu_list_article.ContentID = content_info.ContentID
JOIN subsubmenu ON subsubmenu.ssid=menu_list_article.MenuID
JOIN submenu ON submenu.sid=subsubmenu.sid
JOIN mainmenu ON mainmenu.mid=submenu.mid
WHERE menu_list_article.MenuID LIKE 'SSMN%'

) UNION 
 (
    SELECT 
    content_info.ContentID, 
    content_info.Title,
    menu_list_article.MenuID as article_parent,
    submenu.title as article_parent_title,
    mainmenu.mid,
    mainmenu.title as mid_title,
    mainmenu.module
FROM `content_info`
JOIN menu_list_article ON menu_list_article.ContentID = content_info.ContentID
JOIN submenu ON submenu.sid=menu_list_article.MenuID
JOIN mainmenu ON mainmenu.mid=submenu.mid
WHERE menu_list_article.MenuID LIKE 'SMN%'
 )
)
WHERE mainmenu.mid='MN-0053'
```

Comment: Just type the title of your question in google.com

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a shot at answering this "question":

```
SELECT 
    content_info.ContentID, 
    content_info.Title,
    menu_list_article.MenuID as article_parent,
    submenu.title as article_parent_title,
    mainmenu.mid,
    mainmenu.title as mid_title,
    mainmenu.module
FROM `content_info`
INNER JOIN menu_list_article ON menu_list_article.ContentID = content_info.ContentID
INNER JOIN submenu ON submenu.sid=menu_list_article.MenuID
INNER JOIN mainmenu ON mainmenu.mid=submenu.mid
WHERE menu_list_article.MenuID LIKE 'SSMN%' and mainmenu.mid='MN-0053'
 UNION 
    SELECT 
    content_info.ContentID, 
    content_info.Title,
    menu_list_article.MenuID as article_parent,
    submenu.title as article_parent_title,
    mainmenu.mid,
    mainmenu.title as mid_title,
    mainmenu.module
FROM `content_info`
INNER JOIN menu_list_article ON menu_list_article.ContentID = content_info.ContentID
INNER JOIN submenu ON submenu.sid=menu_list_article.MenuID
INNER JOIN mainmenu ON mainmenu.mid=submenu.mid
WHERE menu_list_article.MenuID LIKE 'SMN%' and mainmenu.mid='MN-0053'
```

There is no reason to have the subselect in the 1st query, I moved the outmost where criteria into the 2 queries, and I defined the joins as inner joins (you may have to use left or right join based on your requirements, but I cannot guess those).

Next time pls describe what your question is and give us more background information on the task.

Comment: By Doing this I only found SMN% LIKE data, I need both

Comment: I do not see your data. If the above query does not return and SSMN menu ids, then it may be that there is no record where menu id starts with SSMN and the mainmenu id is MN-0053. You should provide sample data and expected outputs, then I can refine the above query. Otherwise, you need to determine what went wrong.

Comment: no, both query works fine individually, and return those data that i wanted.
here is the new post link
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904932/get-submenu-sid-and-submenu-title-from-both-query-in-a-single-query-how)

Comment: Why did you create a new question and not follow it up here? Plus if both queries do what they are supposed to do individually, then their union will do the same. Can you pls specify sample data nad expected results?

Comment: For first query it returns only SSMN data and for second SMN, in both cases data contains submenu.sid and submenu.title. I want these two column data in response to a single query

Comment: 1) If only 2 fields are needed, then why are you selecting a lot more fields than those 2 in the queries? 2) Still you fail to come up with sample data and expected results. If the queries you provided in your question return records on their own, then they will return records in a union as well.

Comment: Then will be the query, please help

Comment: How do you expect me or anyone else to answer your question without further information (sample data, expected results - use sqlfiddle.com)?